# How can I fix my VBA code in Excel to delete certain chart legend entries based on their value?

Tags: excel, vba, legend

I have a graph with 5 series of data.  I want all 5 series to show up on the graph, but I only want 3 of them to show up in the legend.  I'd like for the legend entries to be deleted based on the name of the series... "Target Range Upper" and "Target Range Lower" should be excluded from the legend.

I've got code that I think should work, but I'm getting an error message and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
Sub Charts_RemoveLegendEntry()
Dim i As Long
Dim cht As Chart
Dim lgd As Legend
 Set cht = ActiveChart
   Set lgd = cht.Legend
   For i = cht.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
         Select Case cht.SeriesCollection(i).Name
         Case "Target Range Upper", "Target Range Lower"
                 lgd.LegendEntries(i).Delete
         Case Else
                 ' do nothing
         End Select
   Next
End Sub
```

Oddly, if I swap the bottom portion around like this:

```
Select Case cht.SeriesCollection(i).Name
Case "Target Range Upper", "Target Range Lower"
     ' do nothing
Case Else
     lgd.LegendEntries(i).Delete
End Select
```

The Macro works perfectly - just doing the inverse of what I want.  It gets rid of the legend entries I want to keep and keeps the ones I want to delete.  I'm not understanding why it doesn't work both ways.

I'll need to do this for a couple other graphs in the workbook as well, but if I can figure 1 out, I should be able to adjust for the others.

*UPDATE EDIT

Changing `For i = cht.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1` to `For i = lgd.LegendEntries.Count To 1 Step -1` worked for this graph.  However, I tried to recreate the macro for a different graph on a different worksheet and I am now getting a "**Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set**" error message.  What am I missing?  Here is my 2nd code for the next worksheet...

```
    Sub Charts_RemoveLegendEntry2()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim lgd As Legend
     Set cht = ActiveChart
       Set lgd = cht.Legend
       For i = lgd.LegendEntries.Count To 1 Step -1
             Select Case cht.SeriesCollection(i).Name
             Case "Total", ""
                     lgd.LegendEntries(i).Delete
             Case Else
                     ' do nothing
             End Select
       Next
End Sub
```

It appears to be breaking on the `For i = lgd.LegendEntries.Count To 1 Step -1` line.

Comment: What is the error message, and on which line?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. It should work. Like Rory mentioned what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: BTW what happens if you use `For i = lgd.LegendEntries.Count To 1 Step -1` instead of `For i = cht.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1`

Comment: This is the error I get when the macro is called:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Automation error
Unspecified error

And it seems to be triggered by the "Case Else" line of the code

Comment: I tried using     'For i = lgd.LegendEntries.Count To 1 Step -1'    and that seems to have done the trick.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @siddharthrout - Any ideas why my 2nd version of this code isn't working the same way as the 1st one?  See edited post

Comment: Does it have any legends?

Comment: Yes it does.  
There are 7 series in the graph which is a combination graph.  The first 6 series are in a stacked column format and the 7th is a line that I use to total up the other 6 series.  The line is transparent and only the data labels show in the graph.
I want the title for the 7th series (the line) to not show in the legend.  But if I just delete it manually, it comes back whenever the data is reset.